# Tradingview Occasional False Alarms

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5, pine-editor

There is an indicator that I have shared the codes below. The alarms I set are working incorrectly. It can send fake signals without showing "buy" or "sell" on the screen. How can we make this work only after typing buy and sell on the screen and the candle is closed?
I want the buy alarm to work only when buy appears on the screen, and the sell alarm when sell appears. I don't want broken alarms generated in between.

````
//Original Script > @DonovanWall

// Actual Version > @guikroth


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Settings for 5min chart, BTCUSDC. For Other coin, change the paremeters
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


study(title="Range Filter  5min", overlay=true)

// Source

src = input(defval=close, title="Source")

// Sampling Period
// Settings for 5min chart, BTCUSDC. For Other coin, change the paremeters

per = input(defval=100, minval=1, title="Sampling Period")

// Range Multiplier

mult = input(defval=3.0, minval=0.1, title="Range Multiplier")

// Smooth Average Range

smoothrng(x, t, m) =>
    wper = t * 2 - 1
    avrng = ema(abs(x - x[1]), t)
    smoothrng = ema(avrng, wper) * m
    smoothrng
smrng = smoothrng(src, per, mult)

// Range Filter

rngfilt(x, r) =>
    rngfilt = x
    rngfilt := x > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? x - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x - r : 
       x + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x + r
    rngfilt
filt = rngfilt(src, smrng)

// Filter Direction

upward = 0.0
upward := filt > filt[1] ? nz(upward[1]) + 1 : filt < filt[1] ? 0 : nz(upward[1])
downward = 0.0
downward := filt < filt[1] ? nz(downward[1]) + 1 : filt > filt[1] ? 0 : nz(downward[1])

// Target Bands

hband = filt + smrng
lband = filt - smrng

// Colors

filtcolor = upward > 0 ? color.lime : downward > 0 ? color.red : color.orange
barcolor = src > filt and src > src[1] and upward > 0 ? color.lime : 
   src > filt and src < src[1] and upward > 0 ? color.green : 
   src < filt and src < src[1] and downward > 0 ? color.red : 
   src < filt and src > src[1] and downward > 0 ? color.maroon : color.orange

filtplot = plot(filt, color=filtcolor, linewidth=3, title="Range Filter")

// Target

hbandplot = plot(hband, color=color.aqua, transp=100, title="High Target")
lbandplot = plot(lband, color=color.fuchsia, transp=100, title="Low Target")

// Fills

fill(hbandplot, filtplot, color=color.aqua, title="High Target Range")
fill(lbandplot, filtplot, color=color.fuchsia, title="Low Target Range")

// Bar Color

barcolor(barcolor)

// Break Outs

longCond = close and bool(na)
shortCond = close and bool(na)
longCond := src > filt and src > src[1] and upward > 0 or 
   src > filt and src < src[1] and upward > 0
shortCond := src < filt and src < src[1] and downward > 0 or 
   src < filt and src > src[1] and downward > 0

CondIni = 0
CondIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : CondIni[1]
longCondition = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1
shortCondition = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1

//Alerts

plotshape(longCondition, title="Buy Signal", text="BUY", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.labelup, size=size.normal, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(shortCondition, title="Sell Signal", text="SELL", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.normal, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0)

alertcondition(longCondition, title="Buy Alert", message="BUY")
alertcondition(shortCondition, title="Sell Alert", message="SELL")

//For use like Strategy, 

//1. Change the word  "study" for "strategy" at the top
//2.  Remove the "//" below

//strategy.entry( id = "Long", long = true, when = longCondition )
//strategy.close( id = "Long", when = shortCondition )```
````

Comment: You can make this script as `strategy` and create the alert on this strategy directly.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).